# Unable to find Windows 7 (32-bit) drivers for Dell Inspiron n5010?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 32-bit, dell-inspiron

I'm unable to find 32-bit drivers for Windows 7 for newly purchased Dell Inspiron n5010. It came with FreeDOS so no drivers CD was included. The Dell support site has only drivers for 64-bit Windows Vista and Windows 7.

I need drivers for Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: Wait, a 6GB RAM machine that comes with FreeDOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base load on that machine appears to be 6GB of RAM so they probably have never shipped it with anything but a 64-bit operating system.

That said, I'd assume it has the same hardware as the rest of the 15R series, more or less - try a lower end machine and you'll probably be able to find 32-bit drivers.

Comment: I checked on Dell website for Inspiron 15R series, they are only shipping Windows 7 64-bit.
http://www.dell.com/content/products/productdetails.aspx/inspiron-15r?c=us&l=en&s=corp&~tab=specstab&~lt=popup

Even the downloads in Intel Chipset Support doesn't offer any drivers.
http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Chipsets&ProductLine=Laptop+Chipsets&ProductProduct=Mobile+Intel%C2%AE+5+Series+Chipset&ProdId=3172&LineId=1088&FamilyId=40

Comment: I tried Windows update and it automatically downloaded drivers for Video and LAN but Wireless LAN and Modem were not detected. I guess I have to install a 64-bit version of Windows 7.

Comment: That's interesting that they're shipping 64 across the board, because I am fairly certain there are machines in that line starting at 3GB RAM and most other manufacturers won't bother to load 64 until they break 4.  Honestly, it's good for consistency...just bad for you.  You might be able to find drivers from another manufacturer with equivalent parts in the machine but that's not a sure bet and a LOT of legwork (and I wouldn't know offhand where to point you...) so loading 64-bit Windows is probably the easiest route.

Comment: I got one with 2GB RAM and found some links to drivers for Wireless LAN but since I do have 64-bit Windows I'm going to install it.

Answer (score -2):

Windows 7 32 bit drivers are already present in the driver disk. You would have gotten the driver disk along with the Dell computer when you buy.

While extracting, you just need to check the compatibility of the particular driver.

Comment: The laptop came with FreeDOS not Windows its unlikely he was sent the driver cd for windows.